# Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined - stop showing error

Tags: jquery

I have crawled the other answers on here as this seems to be a topic that comes up a lot however they are not the same as mine.

Those other answers show someone how to solve it by passing something to the property. My question is:

Even though I have this error, is there a way to stop it showing in the console?

I have this error in my console lots of times because it is in a foreach loop. I have wrapped the whole thing in an if as I thought that would solve this issue but it didn't

```
 if (str.includes(arr[item])) { }
```

Sometimes it fails in the loop and that is fine as the if statement stops it running but my other question is: Why does it still show an error, surely the if statement should just return true or false.

Thanks guys

Comment: `str` is undefined. Without seeing more of your code, there's no way to help you further. You're also trying to tackle the wrong issue. Instead of hiding the error (which isn't possible), put the effort in to avoiding it

Comment: str is defined,its the includes bit that doesn't match what is passed, surely?

Comment: No, the error is saying that it cannot find an `includes()` method because the `str` variable is undefined.

Comment: Simplest way to avoid it `if (str && str.includes(arr[item])) { }`. But you likely need to improve your code in order to prevent it.

Comment: str is a string that is set above, it loops though the array and passes the array items to the includes bit for the check. sometimes it matches, sometimes it doesnt. The str must be defined otherwise it would fail on all of them??

Comment: I'll try what you said and see if that makes any difference. :)